# Converting single row to multiple rows in CSV using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV file with 2 columns and multiple rows. I have attached the contents of CSV file used for testing, with 2 columns and 30 rows having data from 2 person. But in real application the number of rows increases with the number of test made. So in practical application the dimension will be 2 columns and (15 times N) row where N is the number of person.

I need the output as N + 1 (header) rows and 15 columns (parameters). Can someone help me with a program to convert it using Powershell?

Gentle remainder that I took 2 readings for testing. In application the number of reading is not sure.

My input text file which is to be converted. The parameter and the corresponding values are separated by comma.

```
Name,Test
Age,18
Gender,Male
Time 1,379
Time 2,290
Time 3,305
Time 4,290
Time 5,319
Time 6,340
Time 7,436
Time 8,263
Time 9,290
Time 10,381
Responses,0
Average Reaction Time,329
Name,Test
Age,18
Gender,Male
Time 1,365
Time 2,340
Time 3,254
Time 4,270
Time 5,249
Time 6,350
Time 7,309
Time 8,527
Time 9,356
Time 10,407
Responses,1
Reaction Time,375
```

My code snippet for delimiting comma and transposing columns and rows

```
import-csv $file -delimiter "," | export-csv $outfile
(gc $outfile | select -Skip 1) | sc $outfile
$filedata = import-csv $outfile -Header Parameter , Value   
$filedata | export-csv $outfile -NoTypeInformation

$Csv = import-csv $outfile
$Rows = @()
$Rows += $csv.Parameter -join ","
$Rows += $Csv.Value -join ","
Get-Process | Tee-Object -Variable ExportMe | Format-Table
$Rows | Set-Content $outfile
```

This is my current CSV file

```
Name,Age,Gender,Time 1,Time 2,Time 3,Time 4,Time 5,Time 6,Time 7,Time 8,Time 9,Time 10,Responses,Average Time,Name,Age,Gender,Time 1,Time 2,Time 3,Time 4,Time 5,Time 6,Time 7,Time 8,Time 9,Time 10,Responses,Average Time
Test,18,Male,379,290,305,290,319,340,436,263,290,381,0,329,Test,18,Male,365,340,254,270,249,350,309,527,356,407,1,375
```

I am expecting an output CSV like this

```
Name,Age,Gender,Time 1,Time 2,Time 3,Time 4,Time 5,Time 6,Time 7,Time 8,Time 9,Time 10,Responses,Average Time   
Test,18,Male,379,290,305,290,319,340,436,263,290,381,0,329
Test,18,Male,365,340,254,270,249,350,309,527,356,407,1,375
```

I have also attached a snap of my actual and received output.

[image: Received Output]

[image: Expected Output]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please post the code you're having trouble with, as well as the data and expected output as text rather than images :)

Comment: Sorry about the mess Mathias. I am new to Stack Overflow. I have edited the same. I have inserted blockcodes with my current CSV file and Expected CSV file as text. Regarding the Code Snippets, I have tried but nothing seems to work. I am very new to Powershell.

Comment: Don't sweat it, we're all new at something sometimes :)

Comment: Sure buddy. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd strongly suggest *not* trying to format the CSV by hand.

If you know that there are *always* exactly 15 rows of properties per person, you can do a nested loop to "chop up" your csv:

```bsh
# import original csv
$rows = Import-Csv $file -Header Name,Value

# outer loop increments by 15 (span of one person) every time
$objects = for($i = 0;$i -lt $rows.Count;$i += 15){
  # prepare an ordered dictionary to hold the properties
  $props = [ordered]@{}
  # generate an inner loop from the offset to offset+14
  $i..($i+14)|%{
    # copy each row to our dictionary
    $props[$rows[$_].Name] = $rows[$_].Value
  }
  # cast our dictionary to an object
  [pscustomobject]$props
}

# convert back to csv
$objects |Export-Csv $outfile -NoTypeInformation
```